# Filter and orderby query parameters not working for one drive graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to use `filter` and `orderby` query parameters to sort or filter the results. But the API is ignoring the query parameters and returning entire results.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives?orderBy=name%20desc
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this isn't documented in the Microsoft Graph documentation (it should be), but from the [OneDrive API documentation itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/optional-query-parameters?view=odsp-graph-online#sorting-collections):

> Note that in OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Server 2016, the `orderby` query string only works with `name` and `url`.

I've added [an issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3165) to the documentation's repository so this issue can hopefully get resolved in the future.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/optional-query-parameters?view=odsp-graph-online#optional-odata-query-parameters
> Works for `name`, `size`, and `lastModifiedDateTime` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original [OneDrive API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_list?view=odsp-graph-online)/[Graph Drive API docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_list) state they support **orderby**, but the actual OneDrive Graph API should be have not support filtering or ordering results. So although we pass the **orderby** parameter, when Microsoft Graph sees a query parameter it doesn't expect, it simply ignoring the **unknown filter/orderby** parameter and returning us an **unfiltered/default-sorted** result.

My test string:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site-id/drives?$select=id, name,webUrl&$orderby=name%20desc
```

So the only suggestion for you is to vote up the existing feature request in [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or submit a new one.